# Managing deployment scripts in the process of continuous delivery

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-delivery, scm

My question concerns **deployment scripts** in the process of **continuous delivery**.

Continuous delivery recommends that deployment scripts should be versioned into SCM just as normal code.

- What is the best practice to avoid issues such as checking out (e.g. from Git) a script that does not have the right permission or is not executable?
- Also, where in the SCM repository should deployment scripts be located?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: OK. I am in the process of editing my question. Bear with me...

Comment: I have posted an answer to my own question. @gnat: I did research but I was not able to find information relevant to this specific issue in the context of continuous delivery...

Comment: I was also looking for advice from people who have already met this problem in a real-life project and would share it with me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be noted that solutions to this issue are bound to be specific to the underlying technology.

Here is a couple of git and Unix-specific solutions that can serve as a source of inspiration for other SCMs and platforms:

Both rely on the following git command:

```
git update-index --chmod=+x $script
```

and git/bash aliases. See full post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22710807/536299

Regarding the question of the location in the SCM repository, it could be in a separate SCM repository or in a folder located with the source code.

Comment: How does that answer the question, where in the SCM the things should be located? I'm just asking ... ;-)